# Prove that a denumerable set can be partitioned into two denumerable subsets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I was wondering if this "proof" is sufficient in demonstrating a that a denumerable set $A$ can be partitioned into two denumerable subsets $A_1$ and $A_2$.

Let $A$ be a denumerable set and define $A = A_1 \cup A_2$ where $A_1$ and $A_2$ are infinite subsets of $A$, and therefore they are also denumerable. Because $A$ is denumerable, a bijective function $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow A$ exists. Since $A = A_1 \cup A_2$ we can write $f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow A_1 \cup A_2$. Because $f$ is bijective, the set $A_1 \cap A_2 = \varnothing$ (I think it might be sufficient to say that, because $f$ is a function, the two subsets must be disjoint). Finally, the denumaribility of the two subsets imply that they are not empty.

So if we let the set $P = \{A_1, A_2\}$, the above information allows us to conclude that $P$ is a partition of $A$.

Comment: How do you know a denumerable set has an infinite subset with infinite complement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your argument is circular: you’ve *started* with denumerable sets that form a partition, when what you need to show is that such sets exist.

HINT: Use the fact that there’s a bijection $f:\Bbb N\to A$. Pick a partition of $\Bbb N$ into two denumerable sets; there’s one that’s especially obvious and easy to describe. If these sets are $N_0$ and $N_1$, consider the subsets $f[N_0]$ and $f[N_2]$ of $A$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It seems that the two obvious subsets are the set  $N_1$ of even natural numbers and the set $N_2$ of odd natural numbers. Since these sets infinite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$, they are denumerable. If we consider the image $f(\mathbb{N}) = f(N_1 \cup N_2) = f(N_1) \cup f(N_2) = A$, it seems to be clear that a partition on $A$ has been formed.

Comment: @Benedict: Yes, that’s exactly what I had in mind. You’re welcome.

Answer (score 1):

One problem with your argument is the following. Nothing prevents us from taking $A_1=A_2=A$. Then you can certainly see that your conclusion that $A_1\cap A_2=\varnothing$ is incorrect.